# Redimensionar imagem Wordpress Script

Tags: php, wordpress, script, funções

Encontrei esse script para wordpress, para pegar a imagem do post e adicioná-la no tema do wordpress.

Veja o script:

```
function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
$new_img_tag = "";

ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post-   >post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image with 0 width
$new_img_tag = "<img src='/images/noimage.jpg' width='0px' class='alignleft' />";
}

 else{
 $new_img_tag = "<img src='" .  $first_img . "' width='100px' height='100px'    class='alignleft' />";
}

return $new_img_tag;
}
```

---

### fim do script

Esse pequeno código nós adicionamos para chamar a imagem em algum local do tema.

```
    <?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

Como podem ver o script deixa a imagem dimensionada em 100x100, eu gostaria de controlar o tamanho da imagem por esse código :

```
      <?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
```

Eu preciso deixar a imagem em cada página com dimensões diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal passar as dimensões por parâmetro?

```
function catch_that_image($w, $h) {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    $new_img_tag = "";

    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image with 0 width
        $new_img_tag = "<img src='/images/noimage.jpg' width='0px' class='alignleft' />";
    }

    else{
       $new_img_tag = '<img alt="' . $post->post_title . '" src="' . $first_img . '" width="' . $w . '" height="' . $h . '" class="alignleft" />';
    }

    return $new_img_tag;
}
```

Uma vez assim, basta chamar a função `<?php echo catch_that_image(150, 150) ?>`, ou com quaisquer outros valores que você queira.

**EDIT**

Adicionei a tag `alt`, usando o `get_the_title()` do wordpress. Como este código está (é o que me parece, pelo menos) fora do loop, o `the_title()` não funcionaria, conforme a [documentação](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

**EDIT 2**

Depois de uma análise mais detalhada, é muito mais inteligente usar `$post->post_title` do que `echo get_the_title($post->ID)`. Demorei um pouco pra entender o que eu mesmo havia dito...

Comment: testei aqui e deu certo! Teria como adiciona a Tag Alt e Title na imagem? usando como base o <?php the_title(); ?> do wordpress? t

Comment: Provavelmente. Veja a resposta editada, @user3192159. Não testei, mas deve funcionar sem problemas

Comment: O codigo alt parece ter algum erro, ele não está mostrando o titulo apenas uma parte do titulo, exemplo: Titulo carros azuis, na tag alt aparece alt="carros" azuis src=" "  a tag alt está fechando antes de pegar todo o titulo.

Comment: @user3192159 coloque um `echo` antes do `get_the_title()`. Editei a resposta

Comment: ao adiciona o echo antes do get_the_title() o codigo apresenta um erro.

Comment: Agora que eu me toquei. Já que você tem a global `$post`, você pode dar um `echo` direto no título. `echo $post->post_title;`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25117/discussion-between-caio-felipe-pereira-and-user3192159).

Comment: Olá caio, blz, encontrei um erro no script, não tinha percebido pq não tinha visto todas as pagina do site. Acontece que artigos que tem um iframe ou embed do youtube,  o script ao invés de pegar a imagem do artigo, ele ta pegando o link do iframe src="//www.youtube.com/get_player"  não teria como força o script pegar apenas imagens Jpeg, jpg, png, gif dos artigos e ignora iframe?